# iptables setup for docker microservices

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, docker, centos7

I've followed various instructions for setting up iptables rules to allow access to docker services, but depending on the solution I use it either opens too many ports leaving containers directly accessible from the internet, or does not open port 80 meaning no services are accessible. My setup is as follows: [image]

So a user on the internet wants to access www.mywebsite.com. The request comes in on port 80 but needs to be redirected to my reverse proxy, which is running in a docker container exposing port 8080 ("Container 1"). The reverse proxy should then forward the request onto the server hosting the website, in my case the webserver is a node / express app hosted in "Container 2", which exposes port 8081.

What rules do I need to limit inbound traffic to port 80, forward port 80 onto Container 1's port 8080, have Container 1 communicate with Container 2, and do I need any specific rules for Container 2 to send the pages back to the client?

Comment: The best way to forward incoming traffic on port 80 to the Container_1 on port 8080 is to use "-p" option when you run you run your docker container. For the second question - if you have set ALLOW policy on INPUT table in iptables firewall, you don't need to setup configuration to allow traffic between containers. But the other think is, the better way to have allowed traffic between docker containers is to connect them to the same docker network (please look on `docker network help` command).

Comment: I tried the `-p` option but when i do a port scan on the server, i see port 80 and 8080 are open on the firewall, which is not ideal

Comment: So you can use iptables to DROP/REJECT traffic on port 8080 from the interface connected to the internet. Please read this: https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/

Comment: How you need to configure your Container 1 depends on the proxy you are using. As for the Firewall: try `iptables -t nat -A --dport 80 PREROUTING -i INTERFACE -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to CONTAINER-1-IP:8080`. Exchange INTERFACE with your external interface (e.g. eth0 or wan0) and CONTAINER-1-IP with the internal IP of Container 1. Note that you also have to enable forwarding to this IP: `iptables -A FORWARD -i INTERFACE -p tcp --dport 80 -d CONTAINER-1-IP -j ACCEPT`

Comment: Broco - In your second `iptables` command i had to change `--dport 80` to `--dport 8080` but then it started working. Port scan only shows i ave port 80 open and my website is accessible!